# How to populate a DataTable with a list of Apache Log Files

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, datatable, logfile

This is the basic issue:

I want to parse a log file into a table and format each col by IP, Status Code, and Size of the file all of them common Apache format log file (CLF). Please how to do that. Thanks in advance.

This is a common sample of LogFile pre-formatted by Apache.

```
in24.inetnebr.com - - [01/Aug/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-68/news/sts-68-mcc-05.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 1839
uplherc.upl.com - - [01/Aug/1995:00:00:07 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 304 0
uplherc.upl.com - - [01/Aug/1995:00:00:08 -0400] "GET /images/ksclogo- medium.gif HTTP/1.0" 304 0
uplherc.upl.com - - [01/Aug/1995:00:00:08 -0400] "GET /images/MOSAIC-logosmall.gif HTTP/1.0" 304 0
uplherc.upl.com - - [01/Aug/1995:00:00:08 -0400] "GET /images/USA-logosmall.gif HTTP/1.0" 304 0
```

Comment: do you mean a jQuery dataTables ...?

Comment: Yes. Use Apache LogFiles with JQuery separated like this `127.0.0.1 davemicrovalley dave [01/Aug/2015:00:00:01 -0400] "GET images HTTP/1.0" 200 128` to get a list of logs and save maybe to databases.